# Pass click through to fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static element that is above a fixed element.  When the upper static element is clicked, I want to pass this click through to the fixed element.  How can I do this?  Here is a working example (I wasn't able to get this to work in JSFiddle).

```
<body>
    <div class="lower" onclick="lowerClick()"></div>
    <div class="upper" onclick="upperClick()"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function lowerClick() {
        alert("LOWER CLICK");
    };
    function upperClick() {
        alert("UPPER CLICK");
    };
</script>


//CSS file
.lower {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:blue;
}
.upper {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: static;
    background-color:red;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I thought that adding `pointer-events:none` to my upper element would make this work, but when I click the top element, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `pointer-events:none` works expectedly. But what prevents you from clicking on the `lower` is the `body` element. Because of setting `z-index:-1` on your `lower`, it will be sent to behind of its  parent (which is the `body`). So you can set the `z-index` of the `body` to a more negative number, of course the `postion` should be some value other than `static` (default):

```
body {
  z-index:-1000;
  position:relative;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQnn9/5/)

Comment: What is the z-index of body?

Comment: @Nosrettap every element has `z-index` property, body also has a one, is that not OK?

Comment: Ideally I don't want to change the z-index of body, but I think I can find a way around that.  But if I'm understanding you correctly, the body element always (unless someone explicitly sets it otherwise), has a z-index of 1?  By specification?

Comment: @Nosrettap I think all elements have the default z-index of `0`. But you set the `z-index` of the `.lower` to `-1`, it will be hidden behind the body. You can still see the `.lower` because the body has no background. Even specifying some background for the body is not enough, you have to specify the background for ***both*** the body and the `html` element to see the `.lower` hidden.

Comment: @Nosrettap in fact in your case the `body` has the height of about the height of the `.upper`, so the lower part is totally clickable. If you set the `height` of the body (and the `html`) to `100%`, you'll see that it won't be clickable, check this http://jsfiddle.net/2j5s8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css for the upper div

```
.upper {
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

...also avoid negative z-index, and instead use 1 for lower and 2 for upper. Also why put static and not absolute element at the top?

Comment: I've already tried pointer-events and that doesn't work.  The z- indexes numbers were just for this example and I don't think changing it to absolute will sove anything

Comment: try it before you trash it. Also keep in mind that some browsers don't have support for pointer-events:none.... (internet explorer up to 10 don't)